# Silverlight page navigation?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have three xaml pages page1.xaml, page2.xaml and page3.xaml,

1. how to navigate page1.xaml on button1 click event to Page2.xaml?
2. how to open Page3.xaml as a popup on button2 click  event of page1.xaml?

I have seen multiple answers but not able to find any exact solution that's why I've tried here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the intersoft controls here but the same principle applys for standard buttons

```
Intersoft:UXNavigationButton 
        Content="View Error Log" 
        NavigateUri="/ServerSideOperation/ErrorLog"
```

Your code would look something like:

```
Button Content="Go to Page 2" NavigateUri="/Page2"
```

For the Pop Up you will need to use a child window.
Google for Childwindow and check the examples.